# One @Service for multiple entities in Spring

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I have 3 related entities `Tag`, `SubcategoryTag`, `CategoryTag` and I want to create a common `@Service` for all 3.

How should my Service look?

```
public class Tag {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "optimized-sequence")
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "name", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(name = "tag_type")
    private TagType tagType;

    @ManyToMany
    private Set<QuestionTemplate> questionTemplates;
}
```

Subcategory and Category inherit from Tag

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = JOINED)
@Table(name = "T_TAG")
public class SubcategoryTag extends Tag {
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = LAZY)
    private CategoryTag parentTag;
}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = JOINED)
@Table(name = "T_TAG")
public class CategoryTag extends Tag {
    @OneToMany(orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<SubcategoryTag> subcategoryTagSet;
}
```

Comment: Seems like you are mixing `@Service` with `@Repository` annotation? What you want is a generic repository for your entities. Search for that on google or SO and you get your answer. E.g. https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-the-discriminatorcolumn-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: I had separate tables in DB for Category and Subcategory, now I want to add Tag entity and to store all in the same DB table. Earlier I had 2 @Service class for Category and Subcategory, now I want to implement all business logic in one TagService class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create repositories for the three entities

`public interface TagRepo extends JpaRepository<Tag, Long>{}`

`public interface SubcategoryRepo extends JpaRepository<Subcategory, Long>{}`

`public interface CategoryTagRepo extends JpaRepository<CategoryTag,Long>{}`

then add the service class and Autowire the three repositories.

```
@Service
public class TagService {
    @Autowired
    TagRepo tagRepo;

    @Autowired
    SubcategoryRepo subcategoryRepo;

    @Autowired
    CategoryTagRepo categoryTagRepo;

    //Add your methods
    }
```